# @JsonIgnore and @JsonProperty on same attribute

Tags: java, json, jackson-databind

I need to ignore certain attributes in my Json Object based on a custom Ignore annotation, which I need only for a certain object mapper. But, for other cases, I need the JsonProperty annotation on it. I am using JacksonAnnotationInstrospector to do this. But when I do so, neither of the annotations get acknowledged.

For instance, I want my output to be such:

Normal object mapper:`{"element3":"C","element_1":"A","element_2":"B"}`

Expected output using Object mapper with JacksonAnnotationInstrospector:`{"element_1":"A"}`

The output I am actually getting with JacksonAnnotationInstrospector:`{"element2":"B","element_1":"A"}`

Following is my code:

```
public class TestClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(new JsonIgnoreIntrospector());

        MockObject mockObject = new MockObject("A", "B", "C");
        String string = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(mockObject);
        System.out.println(string);
    }

    public static class MockObject {

        @JsonProperty("element_1")
        String element1;

        @CustomJsonIgnore
        @JsonProperty("element_2")
        String element2;

        @CustomJsonIgnore
        String element3;

        public MockObject(String element1, String element2, String element3) {
            this.element1 = element1;
            this.element2 = element2;
            this.element3 = element3;
        }

        public String getElement1() {
            return element1;
        }

        public void setElement1(String element1) {
            this.element1 = element1;
        }

        public String getElement2() {
            return element2;
        }

        public void setElement2(String element2) {
            this.element2 = element2;
        }

        public String getElement3() {
            return element3;
        }

        public void setElement3(String element3) {
            this.element3 = element3;
        }
    }

    public static class JsonIgnoreIntrospector extends JacksonAnnotationIntrospector {
        @Override
        public boolean hasIgnoreMarker(final AnnotatedMember m) {
            return m.hasAnnotation(CustomJsonIgnore.class) || m.hasAnnotation(JsonIgnore.class);
        }

    }

    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.LOCAL_VARIABLE, ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR})
    @JacksonAnnotation
    public @interface CustomJsonIgnore {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use annotation on getters rather than on fields. and also add METHOD in annotation target.

working solution:

```
public class TestClass  {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(new JsonIgnoreIntrospector());

        MockObject mockObject = new MockObject("A", "B", "C");
        String string = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(mockObject);
        System.out.println(string);
    }

    public static class MockObject {

        String element1;

        String element2;

        String element3;

        public MockObject(String element1, String element2, String element3) {
            this.element1 = element1;
            this.element2 = element2;
            this.element3 = element3;
        }

        @JsonProperty("element_1")
        public String getElement1() {
            return element1;
        }

        public void setElement1(String element1) {
            this.element1 = element1;
        }

        @CustomJsonIgnore
        @JsonProperty("element_2")
        public String getElement2() {
            return element2;
        }

        public void setElement2(String element2) {
            this.element2 = element2;
        }

        @CustomJsonIgnore
        public String getElement3() {
            return element3;
        }

        public void setElement3(String element3) {
            this.element3 = element3;
        }
    }

    public static class JsonIgnoreIntrospector extends JacksonAnnotationIntrospector {
        @Override
        public boolean hasIgnoreMarker(final AnnotatedMember m) {
            return m.hasAnnotation(CustomJsonIgnore.class) || m.hasAnnotation(JsonIgnore.class);
        }

    }

    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @Target({ ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.LOCAL_VARIABLE,
            ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR })
    @JacksonAnnotation
    public @interface CustomJsonIgnore {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not totally sure if I understand you use case. Why do you need a name on a property that you are ignoring?
If the issue is related to deserialisation and the deserialisation fails because it cannot find the desired property with a specific name, you can configure the object mapper to ignore unknown properties. Example follows.

```
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
```